# Rendering unsigned 8-bit textures specificities

Tags: webgl2

I have been trying to use integer-based textures (see this question for context), but I can't manage to make the transition from float-based textures `gl.RGBA/gl.RGBA` to `gl.RGBA8UI/gl.RGBA_INTEGER`.

I've replaced mentions of `sampler2D` to `usampler2D`, `vec4` to `uvec4` (for `fragColor`), rewritten the texture formats, but nothing is drawn. I couldn't also use glClear either, showing with the error: `glClear: can't be called on integer buffers`. Is there any specificities to have in mind when using integer-based textures?

Edit: It seems that it is working on Google Chrome, not on Firefox?

```js
const baseImage = new Image();
baseImage.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/O6aW2Tg.png';
baseImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
baseImage.onload = function() {
  render(baseImage);
};

const vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec2 position;
out vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main() {
  textureCoordinate = vec2(1.0 - position.x, 1.0 - position.y);
  gl_Position = vec4((1.0 - 2.0 * position), 0, 1);
}`;

const fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
precision highp usampler2D;

uniform usampler2D inputTexture;
in vec2 textureCoordinate;
out uvec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(inputTexture, textureCoordinate);
}`;

function render(image) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [
    vertexShaderSource,
    fragmentShaderSource,
  ]);
  const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
    program,
    'position'
  );
  const inputTextureUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(
    program,
    'inputTexture'
  );
  const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttributeLocation,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0
  );
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  const rawTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rawTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8UI, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

  const outputTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8UI, image.width,
    image.height,
    0, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

  const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    outputTexture,
    0
  );
  gl.viewport(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  // gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.uniform1i(inputTextureUniformLocation, 0);
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rawTexture);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);

  const pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * image.width * image.height);
  gl.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    image.width,
    image.height,
    gl.RGBA_INTEGER,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
  );
  console.log(pixels);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code rendered just fine. It failed on readPixels which we can see in the JavaScript console, firefox printed the error

```
Error: WebGL warning: readPixels: Incompatible format or type.
```

This is an unfortunate [part of the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf).

The spec lists all the internal formats of textures you can create and what format/type combinations of data you can pass to `texImage2D` to upload data to each of them. But, going the opposite way it is not as explicit which format/type combinations you can use to read pixels.

This is what it says, section 4.3.2

> Only two combinations of format and type are accepted in most cases. The first varies depending on the format of the currently bound rendering surface. For normalized fixed-point rendering surfaces, the combination format `RGBA` and type
>   `UNSIGNED_BYTE` is accepted. For signed integer rendering surfaces, the combination format `RGBA_INTEGER` and type `INT` is accepted. For unsigned integer rendering surfaces, the combination format `RGBA_INTEGER` and type `UNSIGNED_INT` is accepted.
>
> The second is an implementation-chosen format from among those defined
>   in table 3.2, excluding formats `DEPTH_COMPONENT` and `DEPTH_STENCIL`. The
>   values of format and type for this format may be determined by calling **GetIntegerv** with the symbolic constants `IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT`
>   and `IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE`, respectively. ... The implementation-chosen format may vary depending on the format of the selected read buffer of the currently bound read framebuffer.
>
> Additionally, when the internal format of the rendering surface is RGB10_A2,
>   a third combination of format RGBA and type UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV
>   is accepted.

Table 3.2, which you can see a version of [on this page](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html) 4th table on the page, lists tons a format/type combos and it's important to note the spec does not dictate which format/type combos are valid. In other words it does **not** say pick a format/type combo from table 3.2 that corresponds to the current internal format. Instead it just says any format/type combo in that table is valid. Yes, you read that right. According to the spec you could upload RGBA/INT textures and the implementation might decide your second format is R/FLOAT ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Here's some code to print out the 2nd allowed readPixels format/type combo for a RGBA8UI texture

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }

  const outputTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8UI, 4, 4,
    0, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    outputTexture,
    0
  );

  console.log(
    `format/type: ${
      glEnumToString(gl, gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT))
    }/${
      glEnumToString(gl, gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE))
    }`);
  
}
main();

function glEnumToString(gl, value) {
  for (const key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === value) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return `0x${value.toFixed(16)}`;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If I run the code above Chrome says

```
format/type: RGBA_INTEGER/UNSIGNED_BYTE
```

But firefox says

```
format/type: RGBA_INTEGER/UNSIGNED_INT
```

Both of which are valid according to the spec.

If you want it to work everywhere you need to read the data as `RGBA_INTEGER/UNSIGNED_INT` as the first part of the spec above says that format is always supported for unsigned integer formats.

Changing your code to do that makes it work on both browsers

```js
const baseImage = new Image();
baseImage.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/O6aW2Tg.png';
baseImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
baseImage.onload = function() {
  render(baseImage);
};

const vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec2 position;
out vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main() {
  textureCoordinate = vec2(1.0 - position.x, 1.0 - position.y);
  gl_Position = vec4((1.0 - 2.0 * position), 0, 1);
}`;

const fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
precision highp usampler2D;

uniform usampler2D inputTexture;
in vec2 textureCoordinate;
out uvec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(inputTexture, textureCoordinate);
}`;

function render(image) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [
    vertexShaderSource,
    fragmentShaderSource,
  ]);
  const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
    program,
    'position'
  );
  const inputTextureUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(
    program,
    'inputTexture'
  );
  const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttributeLocation,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0
  );
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  const rawTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rawTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8UI, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

  const outputTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8UI, image.width,
    image.height,
    0, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

  const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    outputTexture,
    0
  );
  gl.viewport(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  // gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.uniform1i(inputTextureUniformLocation, 0);
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rawTexture);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);

  const pixels = new Uint32Array(4 * image.width * image.height);
  gl.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    image.width,
    image.height,
    gl.RGBA_INTEGER,
    gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
    pixels
  );
  console.log(pixels.slice(0, 40));
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```